# How do you move mouse with Playwright Python?

Tags: python, mouse, playwright

I'm writing a test code to **check if the mouse is moving in the Playwright browser**. I used `pyautogui` in this case to locate current mouse position but that might be the problem, so I was wondering if there is a similar method for Playwright Python?

Please have a look at the code below. It prints out the same coordinates for the start and final mouse positions, which means there's no mouse movement. I have tried adding `page.mouse.up()` and `page.mouse.down()` before and after the `page.mouse.move(100,200)` as shown on the official Playwright Docs [page](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-mouse)  but to no avail. **How do you move mouse with Playwright Python?**

```
import pytest
import pyautogui
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
def test_simple_move():
    mouse_start_position = pyautogui.position()
    print(mouse_start_position)

    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=10)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(r"http://www.uitestingplayground.com/")
        page.mouse.move(100,200)
        mouse_final_position = pyautogui.position()
        print(mouse_final_position)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what the problem here is.
It does have to do with pyautogui and playwright not functioning together correctly. I tried searching around to find how to actually get the current mouse position with playwright, but I did not find anything.

So, here is my conclusion:

How did I figure out the problem, and what actually *is* the problem?

The problem here is that pyautogui actually controls the computer's mouse in this case. It seems like playwright only controls that of the browser. If you add a time.sleep(10) (In order to actually see if the cursor has changed position and to have time to move the cursor at a different position) at the end of the function like so:

```py
def test_simple_move():
    mouse_start_position = pyautogui.position()
    print(mouse_start_position)
    
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=10)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(r"http://www.uitestingplayground.com/")
        page.mouse.move(100,400)
        mouse_final_position = pyautogui.position()
        print(mouse_final_position)

        time.sleep(10)
```

You will then see that the actual cursor does not move. It seems like what playwright is doing here is just moving a "virtual" cursor in its browser. In fact, what I did to prove this was:

1. Launch the code
2. While the delay of 10 seconds is going, move the cursor to another point on the screen.
3. Wait for the code to finish.
4. You will now see how the points are different. [Here are my points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUYLr.png)

Comment: I'm actually aware of this and kept the mouse from moving until the test returned completed in order to avoid interruptions, and that's how I got the same result for both start and final positions. What I want to find out is as each playwright browser has its own mouse process, how how will it be possible to use this mouse process to automate the actions on the individual browser? Thanks for the answers anyway, much appreciated!

Comment: Ah, I see. I am sorry I did not answer your question fully. I actually am not sure... If there was some sort of function set in Playwright to actually move the cursor in some place around the browser, it would be much easier. However, at this point, it is hard for me to give tips. I would suggest to play around with the cursor and find fixed points that you can move to in order to have a valid outcome on each run of the code. You could create your own functions, but that takes a lot of time...